# Laravel repeated delayed job

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, memory-leaks, delayed-job

I am writing Laravel json api using MySQL. What I am trying to do, is whenever user creates record, I want to perform some operation on this record every 24 hours, until some changes are made by admin on this record. So averagely this job will be repeated 10-15 times. this is my job:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\Http\Models\Orders\RoadOrder;

class RoadOrderEprirationHandler implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $order_id;

    public function __construct($order_id)
    {
        $this->order_id = $order_id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $order = RoadOrder::findOrFail($this->order_id);
        //do some tasks and if I need to run this cycle again :
            $roadOrderEprirationHandler = new RoadOrderEprirationHandler($order->id);
            $roadOrderEprirationHandler->dispatch($order->id)->delay(now()->addHours(24));
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I initiate job after previous job was finished if admin didn't modified record and I need to run cycle again. after several cycles, I won't run job again, so it will be finished.

My question:

Is some problem in this implementation? maybe I am doing something wrong or maybe there may occur some type of memory leak (because I create job inside job again and again). I can write this but I need to be sure that this implementation doesn't leads to some type of bugs or errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create a separate table in your DB for that purpose?

You can keep order_ids with status (checked by admin / not checked). Or just put new order_id there and delete it after admin check. So you will only use your jobs to see is there any unchecked ids. Or some kind of that.

I think this approach is more predictable and less buggy.

Comment: listen, I just need to know the problem of my approach.

Comment: Your implementation should work fine. You create new job every time you create RoadOrderEprirationHandler, so there's nothing wrong. If you worry about creating RoadOrderEprirationHandler inside RoadOrderEprirationHandler, try this code (and see, that it works good):
`
class Foo {
    public function tryThis()
    {
        $newOne = new Foo();
        $newOne->printFoo();
    }

    public function printFoo()
    {
        echo 'foo';
    }
}



$foo = new Foo();
$foo->tryThis();
`